# The lines of curvature are the coordinate cuves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

In Do Carmo's *differential geometry of curves and surfaces*, page 160, the differential equation of the asymptotic curves is
$$e(u')^2+2fu'v'+g(v')^2=0$$

and the differential equation of the lines of curvature is(page 161)

$$(fE-eF)(u')^2+(gE-eG)u'v'+(gF-fG)(v')^2=0$$

There is an exercise related to these equations on page 168(part d and part e):

> Consider the parametrized surface
>   $$x(u,v)=(u-u^3/3+uv^2, v-v^3/3+vu^2, u^2-v^2).$$
>
> Some computations show that
>   $$E=G=(1+u^2+v^2)^2, F=0$$
>   $$e=2, g=-2, f=0$$
>
> Part d. The lines of curvature are the coordinate curves.
>
> Part e. The asymptototic curves are $u+v=const$ and $u-v=const$.

My question:

Take d for instance,
when $e=g=0$ and $eg-f^2<0$, we only know $u'v'=0$. Clearly lines of curvature are the coordinate curves satisfy the equations. I wonder why the lines of curvature can only be the coordinate curves and no others?

Specifically, why does $u'(t)v'(t)=0, \forall t$ implies that $$u'(t)=0, \forall t ~~\text{or}~~ v'(t)=0, \forall t?$$ 
Note: We only know that $\forall t, u'(t)=0$ or $v'(t)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a continuity argument. Note that you cannot have any umbilic points, since $K<0$, and so there's no way to switch continuously from $u$-curve to $v$-curve along a single curve. When there are umbilic points, there are no longer everywhere precisely two distinct principal directions and all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean by "there's no way to switch continuously from u-curve to v-curve along a single curve"? How to prove this rigorously?

Comment: Since there are no umbilic points, we can number principal curvatures so that $k_1>k_2$ everywhere. We parametrize so that the $u$-curves are those with $k_1$ as principal curvature and the $v$-curves are those with $k_2$ as principal curvature. This is globally well-defined since principal curvatures vary continuously along a line of curvature. Only when there are umbilic points ($k_1=k_2$) can there be any possibility to have $k_1$ along part of the curve and $k_2$ along another part of the curve.

Comment: To make it slightly more succinct: Following up on my previous comment, consider the function $k_1-k_2$ along any curve. Since this is a continuous function, it cannot ever change sign. In particular, on any line of curvature, it is either always positive or always negative.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I am still seeking for a formal proof for this

Comment: I just gave you one, but ... OK. You absolutely need to use continuity of $k_1$ and $k_2$.